# Setting a value for composite data when property is in a group

Tags: xpages

I have a custom property in my custom control. The custom property is in the Field1 group and is called ClientID.   The group and the field are in my custom property definition.  I want to set it on page load.  So I do the following:

```
compositeData.Field1.ClientID = getClientId("Field1")
```

When I do do I get an error:

'compositeData.Field1' is null

But if I define a property off of the root called Field1_ClientID and do the following:

```
compositeData.Field1_ClientID = getClientId("Field1")
```

Then all works well.  How can I make use of groups in custom properties?

Answer (score 2):

Bruce,

compositeData is a property map. If there is no value in it, compositeData.Field1 will be a null (because it is also a property map).

So you can do this;

```
compositeData.Field1= { ClientID: getClientId("Field1") }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the property "property1" within the group "group1" you can do the following:

`compositeData.group1.property1 = "test";`

You can run the above code in the beforePageLoad or afterPageLoad events of the custom control.

I think that your problem is that you are setting the value in an event which takes place before the custom control has been set up.

Comment: he want's to set it on page load.

Comment: I have updated my answer with beforePageLoad and afterPageLoad events.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I have tried both  Before and AfterPageLoad and get the same error.  Please read my post again.  The error has nothing to do with the control I am setting it to.  It is the issue with the group.  The error I am getting is 'compositeData.Field1' is null.    I even get it if I move it to the onChange event of the field.   Something I have found, if I insert the CC into my Xpage then set the value of Field1.ClientID then I do not get the error.   I also do not get the error if my property is simply called Field1_ClientID and I don't have to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a quick test of the group functionality of the custom control (never used it before).

given a group of "testGroup" and property of "testProp" inside that group.

The following worked in beforePageLoad:

```
compositeData.testProp = "example1";
print("Test1: " + compositeData.testProp);
```

the following did not work:

```
compositeData.testGroup.testProp = "example2";
print("Test2: " + compositeData.testGroup.testProp);
```

I therefore believe the group property may simply be a way of logically grouping properties and not defining an object with multiple properties. Try just referencing the property and not the group.

Comment: What do you mean by "Try just referencing the property and not the group."?   It would be nice to be able to group these properties.

Comment: as my code sample shows if its in a group you can still get to the value by just using compositeData.value rather than compositeData.group.value . you can still group them but when referencing them call them via compositeData.value

Comment: I think I understand now.  I can create the property as part of a group but still be able to set them by simply ignoring the group name?   That won't work for me.  What I wanted to do is have something like Field1.Value, Field1.ID, Field2.Value, Field2.ID.

Comment: ok in that case why not put a js object in a field. So create properties such as field1, field2 (not in groups). and use something like compositeData.field1 = {id: "testId", value: "testVal"}; I gave it a quick test and it works e.g. print("Value: " + compositeData.field1.value);

Comment: the code in my previous comment is a direct copy from a test i did on my machine. it does work.

Comment: Oh I see now.  I missed the "not in groups" part.   OK I will give that a try.   Still kind of defeats the great idea of properties that I can look at it when I drop the CC in my Xpage though I suppose that can be documented in the description.

Comment: Yeah still does not work in Property Maps.  compositeData.field1.id within the CC returns the value just like you said but pm.getProperty("field1.id") within the xPage returns null.

Comment: var obj = pm.getProperty("field1"); print(obj.id); does work. getProperty will be treating field1.id as a string and is looking for a property called that, not the id inside the object thats in field1. you need to pull out the object and then query that for the id

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense now! :)   Sorry for being so dense. :)

Thanks for the tip.  This should work OK.

Comment: did this work? if so can you mark mine or somebody elses answer as top answer so that other developers will know where to go / what to do to fix a similar issue